# Movie where two people meet as strangers and then appear to know each other

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a movie several years ago where a man and a woman meet in an Italian cafe (or restaurant), seemingly as strangers.

(I'm pretty sure it was an Italian setting, but it might have been another Mediterranean country). I can't remember the language of the film. I'd say English if I had to guess.

They begin talking, apparently as strangers, but as the conversation unfolds they make some unusual remarks to one another, as if they already know each other. At some point they get into a car together and begin to argue. Towards the end of the film it appears that they are a married couple. The film is primarily dialogue between the two individuals.

Throughout the film the viewer is left guessing as to the true nature of their relationship.

It was a modern film (post 2000) and as I recall it might have been an adaptation of a play (or at least there was a play with a similar topic, but the name of that escapes me as well).

Can anyone suggest the name of this film? I tried various Google searches but nothing was revealed.

Comment: [Before Sunset](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0381681/)?

Comment: @madmada no that's not it, thanks for giving it a crack though!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_Sunshine_of_the_Spotless_Mind ???

Comment: @Dexter unfortunately not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Kiarostami's [Certified Copy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1020773/combined) from 2010 with Juliette Binoche.

> In Tuscany to promote his latest book, a middle-aged British writer meets a French woman who leads him to the village of Lucignano. While there, a chance question reveals something deeper.

It's comprised almost exclusively of their conversations as they walk around Tuscany (where they indeed visit one or two cafes and argue in a car), and oddly, as the film progresses the 2 strangers suddenly start talking like they've actually been married for 15 years and have a son together. Worth watching for Binoche alone, who gives a great performance. Here's the trailer:

Answer (score 0):

I imagine there are a number of such movies.  The one that occurs to me, given that the OP thinks is appeared on TV in the early 2000's, was released in 1996.  It's titled *Lone Star* directed by John Sayles.  The cast includes Kris Kristofferson, Matthew McConaughey, Chris Cooper and Elizabeth Peña.  But this film is not set abroad, rather it takes place in a small Texas town not far from the Mexican border.  Still, with all the bright sunshine in the film and the presence of Elizabeth Peña, who might be thought Mediterranean rather than Texan, particularly if one couldn't hear the spoken dialogue, in the OP's memory the setting may have uh, traveled a bit?

Comment: Well my memory might have travelled a bit but not that far!

Comment: I'm pretty sure if it had been Lone Star, they would have provided significantly different details. ;)  Props for a [John Sayles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Sayles) mention though!

Comment: Yes, when I re-read the OP a second time (after posting my Lone Star response) I realized it wasn't very likely the film the OP was seeking was not Lone Star.